# Twitter API: Application Oauth Token Expiring Repeatedly

Tags: java, api, twitter, oauth, twitter4j

I have created a Twitter bot for some actions on my account. The actions are performed in bulk operations.

The application is still in development mode so I don't have it authorized with the Twitter system.

My problem is as follows: whenever I execute the program to test it, the valid token becomes expired. Checking within apps.twitter.com, I noticed that I have to regenerate the `OAuth` token, as if I had never generated it in the first place. I have not received any kind of notification as to why the token expired or was removed.

Can anyone guide me as to why this is happening?